# Addressing Composite-Keyed 1NF Matlab Table with Arrays

Tags: matlab

## The Problem

Consider a Table object, `tbl`, defined below, that holds 1NF normalized information with a 2 part composite key comprised of the unordered tuple of the `Species1` and `Species2` column values.

```matlab
% build table ( in place of readtable )
dat =  {"example1" "example1" "example1" "example2" "example4" "example3"; ...
        "example2" "example3" "example4" "example3" "example2" "example4"; ...
        0.1896     -0.0119    -0.0070    0.3257     0.1140     0.2086   };
tbl = cell2table(dat','VariableNames', {'Species1','Species2','k_ij'});

% clear temp vars
clear('dat')
```

You are given a one dimentional string array, `names` that holds some set of keys that can appear in either the `Species1` or `Species2` columns.

```matlab
% Make an example 1x4 string array 
names = ["example1" "example2" "example3" "example4"];
```

How can a *n*x*n* array of values from the `k_ij` column, as indexed by all combinations of the elements in names, be constructed? *Can this be done only with matrix operations?*

Assume that any self-self interactions have a zero value; that is `k_ij` = 0 when the two keys equal one another.

```matlab
%       spec.1  spec.2  spec.3  spec.4
out = [ 0       0.1896 -0.0119 -0.0070; ... % species 1
        0.1896  0       0.3257  0.1140; ... % species 2
       -0.0119  0.3257  0       0.2086; ... % species 3
       -0.0070  0.1140  0.2086  0     ]     % species 4
```

---

### My Aproach Thusfar

My intuition is that it would be best to approach this by forming a *n*x*n* array holding all combinations of `names`, which you can see below.

```matlab
% make grids come together
[names_1, names_2] = meshgrid(names,names');

% cross join the names 
names_mat = reshape(                ...
    cat(2,names_1',names_2'),   ...
    length(names),              ...
    length(names),              ...
    2);

% clear temp vars
clear('names_1','names_2')
```

I think that the next step would be to attempt to use the values in `names(i,j,:)` to address `tbl` and extract an *n*x*n* array values associated from the `k_ij` column, and to add this to `out` to get some matrix of the form shown below.

***This is the part that I cannot figure out***

```matlab
%       spec.1  spec.2  spec.3  spec.4
tmp = [ NaN     0.1896 -0.0119 -0.0070; ... % species 1
        NaN     NaN     0.3257  NaN   ; ... % species 2
        NaN     NaN     NaN     0.2086; ... % species 3
        NaN     0.1140  NaN     NaN   ]     % species 4
```

Because we know that the self-self interactions are always going to be zero, we can set the diagnal to be zero.

```matlab
tmp(eye(length(names))==1) = 0
```

this renders a table of the form

```matlab
%       spec.1  spec.2  spec.3  spec.4
tmp = [ 0       0.1896 -0.0119 -0.0070; ... % species 1
        NaN     0       0.3257  NaN   ; ... % species 2
        NaN     NaN     0       0.2086; ... % species 3
        NaN     0.1140  NaN     0     ]     % species 4
```

Then we can reflect across the diagnal to get the desired output

```matlab
% grab vals across the diagonal for each value that is NaN
mirror_vals = tmp(isnan(tmp)');
% flip over the diagnal
tmp = tmp';
% stuff grabbed values into NaN indices
tmp(isnan(tmp)) = mirror_vals;
% push to output var
out = tmp; 
% clear temporary varaible
clear('tmp','mirror_vals')
```

---

Comment: Please try `tmp=`[squareform](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/squareform.html)`([dat{3,:}]);`

Comment: @rahnema1 - wow, that's perfect! I knew there had to be a simpler way to do this